# How to get python.exe path from cmd?

Tags: python, vba, windows

I have two pythons installed to my computer. One is a separate version, another is a part of Anaconda package. I use the one which comes with Anaconda (I use Spyder to run it), because the other one doesn't have win32api and so on.

I need to find out the location of python.exe that Spyder is using when it runs the script.

My aim is to run the py script from excel VBA using the code:

```
Sub RunPython()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Users\EEEEEEEEEEEEE\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\os.py"""
PythonScript = """//fileh01/home$/EEEEEEEEEEEEE/Desktop/Python/test.py"""

objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

If I go to anaconda prompt and type `python //fileh01/home$/EEEEEEEEEEEEE/Desktop/Python/test.py` everything works. But when I run code from VBA, nothing happens.

Comment: If you have multiple pythons installed, no tool can guess which one you want. You have to simply know where it is.

Answer (score 1):

In either cmd or the Anaconda prompt, You can find the location of your Python.exe using:

```
where python
```

You could also try:

```
where anaconda
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Anaconda prompt says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in both cases (where python and where anaconda)

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling the Python you do not use to avoid confusion first, then try reinstalling Anaconda, or try to search for it in your files. You have to set the path in Windows first or else nothing will work.